# enabling shell access for cyrus user

Tags: centos, ssh, shell, cyrus

My current cyrus user in `/etc/passwd` looks like this:

```
cyrus:x:76:12:Cyrus IMAP Server:/var/lib/imap:/sbin/nologin
```

I want to be able to give it shell access but restrict it to `/var/lib/imap` and `/var/spool/imap`. How do I enable the shell to allow this using usermod? And once this is done, will the `cyrus` user be able to ssh into the server or should I make changes in sshd_config?

Purpose: Need to rsync mail for backup using `cyrus` user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use an ssh key like I did [recommend here in the past](https://serverfault.com/questions/334448/why-is-ssh-password-authentication-a-security-risk/334483#334483). I'm in a bit of a rush, so I'll just lazily copy-paste my previous text and modify it for rsync purpose. :)

Using ssh keys do have one unique feature compared to password login: you can specify the allowed commands. This can be done by modifying ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file at the server.

For example,

```
command="/usr/bin/rsync", ssh-rsa auiosfSAFfAFDFJL1234214DFAfDFa...
```

would allow only the command `/usr/bin/rsync" with that particular key.

You can also specify the allowed hosts for the key:

```
from="yourclient,yourotherclient", ssh-rsa auiosfSAFfAFDFJL1234214DFAfDFa...
```

Or combine the two:

```
from="yourcyrusserver", command="/usr/bin/rsync", ssh-rsa auiosfSAFfAFDFJL1234214DFAfDFa...
```

With keys you can also grant temporary access to some user (say, a consultant) to a server without revealing the password for that particular account. After the consultant has finished his/her job, the temporary key can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `usermod -s /bin/bash cyrus`. Then, check to see if the nologin has changed using `cat /etc/passwd`. Then try ssh-ing into the server. You should be able to log in to the home directory, which in your example is `/var/lib/imap`

Comment: are there any security risks for this?